# XNA for multiplayer game?

Tags: xna, mmo

I've made a few games without using XNA and recently started to see some documents and samples around and took an interest on it but i have a few doubts for going into it or not.

- What limitations do i have if i am planning to create a mmorpg with XNA for distributing it (if it has a item mall or is paid to play for example) ?
- Do i need more accounts to test it (for example to login into my own game 3 players) or XNA does not cost anything at this level (heard something about LIVE Gold Membership plus which is why i am asking this one) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An MMORPG using XNA over Xbox Live is currently not possible. You can't access servers other than Xbox Live and even then you can't have a dedicated server (although technically you could use another Xbox if you wanted to but even then you would have no external access and would need a really good internet connection) to manage your game state. The marketplace is not available either except for downloading the game itself.

If you develop the game for PC you can have whatever networking code you like, however on Xbox you are very limited as far as multiplayer.

Comment: im not planning on making a client as a server i am planning on making my own server and client... but from what i saw from using XNA people would need to buy my game or how is the licensing of it working

Comment: If you are building for windows, no license, account, or anything else are necessary unless you use XNA's built in networking which supports windows live.

If you add your own networking code you are free to do as you like. Even if you used the XNA networking code, a "silver" free windows live account is sufficient.

Comment: thanks for the replies, just to make sure... i am not tied to anything at all if i want to use XNA to make a p2p or item mall mmo and using my own networking communication i dont need to pay nor do my users and i am free to work it out with my own server ?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely fine. Just don't hope to get it working for xbox.

Comment: Thanks, i am not aiming for xbox at all :) just PC

Answer (score 3):

Using XNA to create an MMORPG for the Xbox 360 Creators Club is not possible since you can't have your own backend servers, but using XNA to create a PC MMORPG is possible.

Using XNA on the PC is extremely possible and frees you from a lot of the Xbox 360 Creators Club restraints.